# Is there algebraic functions with infinitely many roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, reference-request, roots

For example, a rational function is zero if and only if its numerator (which is a polynomial) is zero. Thus, a rational function which is not identically zero have only a finite number of roots.

Is the same conclusion valid for smooth algebraic functions? If so, what would a proof or a source?

**Edit (in response to the comments).** I'm particularly interested in a real-valued function of a real variable given explicitly by a formula obtained from the elementary algebraic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, roots).

Comment: Do you mean univariate functions ?

Comment: What is your definition of smooth algebraic functions? Note that multivariable polynomials can have infinitely many roots.

Comment: With non-standard meanings of "algebraic" we can do this.  I say $x - \sqrt{|x|^2}$ is not "algebraic", but if you say it is, then that is an answer for you.

Comment: @N.S. See my edit.

Comment: " a real-valued function of a real variable given explicitly by a formula obtained from the elementary algebraic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, roots)." ... so you do allow $x - \sqrt{x^2}$, which is zero for $x \ge 0$ and nonzero for $x<0$.

Comment: @GEdgar He probably means "countably many roots". and excludes functions that are on some interval identical to zero

Comment: @Grešnik Actually, my question was more elementary than that and the GEdgar's comment really answers it.

Comment: $$\frac{x^2}{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}+1-\sqrt{1+x^2}$$ is identically 0.

Comment: @N.S. Is your function algebraic in the sense that it satisfies $P(x,f(x))=0$, where $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I mean that.

Comment: @Pedro Well, to quote your question, it is definitely " a formula obtained from the elementary algebraic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, roots)."......... And the answer to your new question is trivially yes, with $$P(x,y)=y$$

Answer (score 5):

Say $F$ is algebraic in the sense that it is real-analytic and satisfies
$$
P_n(x)F(x)^n + P_{n-1}(x)F(x)^{n-1}+\dots+P_1(x)F(x)+P_0(x) = 0
\tag{1}$$
for all $x$, where $P_0,\dots,P_n$ are polynomials, and the left side of $(1)$ is irreducible, that is: it cannot be factored onto two nonconstant expressions of the same form.  Can $F$ have infinitely may zeros?  If $\{x_k\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are zeros of $F$, plug into $(1)$ to conclude they are also zeros of $P_0$.  Since $P_0$ is a polynomial, $P_0 = 0$.  Then $(1)$ can be factored, where one factor is $F(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are even non-zero polynomials $f(x)$ having infinitely many roots. This can happen when we do not consider polynmials over fields, but, say, over the real algebra of quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. The polynomial 
$$
f(x) = x^2+1 
$$
has infinitely many roots in $\mathbb{H}[x]$.